# Export/Import from Enterprise Architect to System Architect?

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to migrate an existing Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect (EA) .eap file for use in UNICOM (previously IBM/Rational) System Architect (SA)? If so, how?

Are there any restrictions on converting from EA to SA when using the DoDAF extensions?

Comment: Look for ability to import/export UML model in the [XMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) file format

Comment: IIRC the supporter on Sparx' forum told that this is not possible for SA. Try a search on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

As always, if both tools support the same XMI version you can get the content across. The diagrams, however, are not likely to make the trip.

Answer (score 0):

I fostered Sparx' forum (still a PITA) and my comment proves right:  [not possible](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,30788.msg223785.html#msg223785).

Answer (score 0):

If the effort behind the model(s) is more than 300 hours, consider porting by self-made script, what XMI could not deliver. Both tools are COM servers.